# Python: discord.py 1.5.1 get_user function always returns None

Tags: python, discord

Same thing title says, get_user always returns None, but its sister function, get_channel, works no problem

this wasn't an issue until the other day

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user}")
    print(client.get_user(anyIDhere))
    print(client.get_channel(anyIDhere))
client.run("token")
```